# VSFTP Users and Directories

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, user-accounts, vsftpd

I'm stuck. I've been working all day on trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and I've hit wall after wall.

**What I'm trying to do:**
Setup FTP in such a way that certain users have access only to their directory, but higher level users have access to all directories.

**What I've Googled so far:**
I started with [this](http://linux-hacks.blogspot.com/2008/09/adding-new-users-to-vsftpd.html), but that didn't do what I needed it to. I then used [this](http://www.noob2geek.com/linux/setup-vsftpd-debian-ubuntu), but once I created one user, it wouldn't let me create another one. Finally, I decided to follow [this](http://howto.gumph.org/content/setup-virtual-users-and-directories-in-vsftpd), but it wouldn't let me even create one user.

I'm using Ubuntu 10. I can login to ftp as a root user and it takes me to the home directory. If I try to login using the user I created in the tutorial it says:

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Command:    USER mathew
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ****
Response:   530 Login incorrect.
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

**EDIT:** I'm still having trouble understanding CHROOT with FTP. Every tutorial I read looks completely different and has me do different things. Every tutorial I read on VSFTP has me doing different things as well. I thought using Linux would be easier to configure and set up, but so far I'm struggling with something that should be simple. It's easier to set up an entire LAMP stack than FTP. **SIGH** Sorry, for the rant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my own question... I used an easier FTP application.
http://www.flynsarmy.com/2010/11/lazy-mans-guide-to-chroot-jailed-ftp/

Quick, dirty. It isn't SFTP or FTPS or FTP over an SSH tunnel, but it is what I was asking for and it works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very specific reason, don't use `ftp`.  It is insecure and limited.

[For more information.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie)

If you still wish to proceed, the information you are looking for is called a 'chroot' and is very possible, but you probably won't find it looking in ftp documentation.  Start with this in Google:  `chroot an FTP user`

If you were to switch to `ssh` where you can use `sftp`, you can set up a chroot environment within about 5 minutes if you're aware of what needs to take place.  Read on to find out more!

The below information is gathered from http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590

### subsystem sftp internal-sftp

You need to configure OpenSSH to use its internal SFTP subsystem.  This needs to be in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

`Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`

### sshd_config

The Chroot environment must be specified within a Match segment.

```
Match group sftponly
     ChrootDirectory /home/%u
     X11Forwarding no
     AllowTcpForwarding no
     ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Notice the `ChrootDirectory` was specified as well as the `ForceCommand`.

### Permissions note

The user's home directory MUST BE OWNED BY ROOT!  This is not optional.  Not only that, but it must also NOT be writable by any user EXCEPT root.  The home directory and ALL parent directories most have these same restrictions.

```
drwxr-xr-x 21 root   root   4096 Jan  1 12:51 /
drwxr-xr-x 16 root   root   4096 Jan 15 14:26 /home
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4096 Jan 15 14:27 /home/chroot
drwxrwxrwx  2 chroot chroot 4096 Jan 15 14:27 /home/chroot/upload
```

Notice the permissions for the user's home directory (`/home/chroot`) are NOT writable even by the owner (an account named `chroot`).  I have created an upload directory that allows modification as an example.  In this setup, the user `chroot` does NOT have write access to their own home directory.  This is intentional and required for sftp chroot.  Again, all parent directories must have similar permissions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in a better direction. I left yesterday pulling out what little hair I had left wondering what I was doing wrong.

Comment: As much as I'd like to set up an SFTP host, I've been given the direction to 'make it the same as the previous one' which means just regular ftp for now.